# How to initialize a javascript array with its own elements and elements of another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, initialization

Here's a sample code that resembles my situation:

```
var customProcessor = function test1(arga, argb, argc, argd) {
  console.log('customProcessor', 'arga', arga);
  console.log('customProcessor', 'argb', argb);
  console.log('customProcessor', 'argc', argc);
  console.log('customProcessor', 'argd', argd);
};

var utilityMethod = function test2(arga, argb, someFunc, cbArgs) {
  console.log('utilityMethod', 'arga', arga);
  console.log('utilityMethod', 'argb', argb);
  cbArgs.unshift(argb);
  cbArgs.unshift(arga);
  someFunc.apply(this, cbArgs); // INTENT: someFunc(arga, argb, argc, argd);
};

utilityMethod('argA', 'argB', customProcessor, ['argC','argD']);
```

The code above manages to pass all 4 required arguments to my `customProcessor` method but the following lines aren't the most readable in terms of intent:

```
  cbArgs.unshift(argb);
  cbArgs.unshift(arga);
  someFunc.apply(this, cbArgs); // INTENT: someFunc(arga, argb, argc, argd);
```

Is there some way to write them in a more self-explanatory fashion ... using a JS syntax that I might not know about?

Here's what I'm imagining would be more readable:

```
  // not real code
  someFunc.apply(this, [arga, argb, cbArgs]);
```

but I need to know if there is a realistic JS syntax for accomplishing this?

Comment: `[arga, argb, ...cbArgs]`

Comment: @ASDFGerte - thanks! would you mind answering so i can mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

`[arga, argb, ...cbArgs]`

Note that this also works directly on the function call, replacing `apply` (if you do not need an explicit `this`), e.g. `someFunc(arga, argb, ...cbArgs)`

Comment: yes you are right again! both work: `someFunc.apply(this, [arga, argb, ...cbArgs]);` or `someFunc(arga, argb, ...cbArgs);`

Comment: @pulkitsinghal make sure to check both tabs in the browser support section as it's not supported in IE and some older bowsers https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 1):

```js
function customProcessor(a, b, c, d) {
  console.log('customProcessor:', a, b, c, d);
};

function utilityMethod(arga, argb, someFunc, cbArgs) {
  console.log('utilityMethod  :', arga, argb);
  someFunc(arga, argb, cbArgs[0], cbArgs[1]); 
  // or
  someFunc.apply(this, [arga, argb].concat(cbArgs)); 
};

utilityMethod('argA', 'argB', customProcessor, ['argC','argD']);
```